# Java(Spring) automatically correcting date by timezone bug

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, date

so I have a task to fix a bug. So basically I make a GET request for /report-information and get in response two fields: *Date dateFrom*, *Date dateTill*.

The correct date that it should return should be: **2019-07-01 00:00:00** and **2019-07-31 23:59:59** - that's the data from a database. Basically, I make a GET request for these fields, Java takes it from database and sends it back to me.

But the problem is that somehow the values that are returned after making a GET request are: **2019-06-30 21:00:00** and **2019-07-31 20:59:59**. Basically -3 hours because of some automatic timezone correction.

What I need is to create a method or something similar that would make java ignore the timezone and wouldn't change the date. I should use *Date* variables not to mess up a lot of other code that uses these fields.

Also I should mention that when I debugged the whole process, somehow in the @RequestMapping method it *returns* these fields correctly, as they should be, but when I make a request through my browser or Postman, I get the corrected by timezone version of the date. But it is possible that I just missed something.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas why and at what moment does Java change the date automatically? And what should I do to prevent it from correcting the date.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned that in your Controller code you can see the correct date, you may want to check the Jackson serializer ( assuming this is the one serializing objects to json ) settings used for serializing the date object into JSON. You can check the multiple options for configuration [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates).

Comment: This is what I can see in my report class. `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
    private Date DateFrom;` What does it tell me? Is the problem here?

Comment: You can use following code to test your expected values https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

Answer (score 1):

i also face this problem some day ago....
in my case it's arise from Jackson lib (i project is in spring boot)

to fix this problem i set my time zone for Jackson lib in application.property file

```
spring.jackson.time-zone:Asia/Dhaka
```

in my case i am in Dhaka Bangladesh

also try by this

[image]

[for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#JACKSON)